# Error in dumbbell plot with facet grid, unable to create a side by side plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I tried plotting a dumbbell plot side by side with a facet grid but got some interesting errors. [image]

Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Trial_type`, `Session.`.

- Plot is missing `Trial_type`, `Session.`
- Layer 1 is missing `Session.`
- Layer 2 is missing `Session.`
- Layer 3 is missing `Session.`
- Layer 4 is missing `Session.`
- Layer 5 is missing `Trial_type`, `Session.`
- Layer 6 is missing `Session.`
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
  2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
  3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
  4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

```
data10A <- structure(list(Session = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), conditon2 = structure(c(10L, 
4L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 
11L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 8L), .Label = c("CEN_LLL", "CTL_LLL", 
"IPS_LLL", "CEN_RRR", "CTL_RRR", "IPS_RRR", "CEN_RLR", "CTL_RLR", 
"IPS_RLR", "CEN_LRL", "CTL_LRL", "IPS_LRL"), class = "factor"), 
    Trial_type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Retention", "Transfer"), class = "factor"), 
    NormalizedJerk_102 = c(1270.168699, 2099.703957, 3259.268053, 
    1152.257445, 3810.890123, 4601.918336, 1792.371775, 1288.768888, 
    2699.08162, 1650.968794, 2018.457394, 6159.567785, 931.350429, 
    1053.84252, 1611.673955, 1034.363607, 5352.195367, 2499.83996, 
    1560.678962, 915.3845866, 1948.757464, 1341.815274, 2113.732859, 
    2051.140838), NormalizedJerk_104 = c(853.7034116, 924.8554548, 
    2268.966702, 675.7160839, 2442.874632, 1603.954653, 1010.111276, 
    794.1752256, 1313.813984, 1197.638788, 1039.577947, 3125.131019, 
    561.2311988, 767.7541159, 1019.744071, 769.6067294, 2232.404471, 
    1292.509181, 884.8343164, 663.0273865, 1230.369444, 717.8466364, 
    1536.027898, 1027.358586), key = c("Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk", "Change in normalized jerk", 
    "Change in normalized jerk")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(dumbbell)
 dumbbell::dumbbell(data10A, id = "conditon2", key = "Trial_type", 
          leg = "Test", 
          column1 = "NormalizedJerk_102", 
          column2 = "NormalizedJerk_104", 
          delt = 1, lab1 = "Pre-test", lab2 = "Post-test", 
          p_col1 = "black", p_col2 = "grey40", 
          textsize = 4, segsize = 1.5, 
          pointsize = 2.5, 
          title = "Change in Normalized jerk from Pre- to Post-test")  + 
   facet_wrap( Trial_type ~ Session., scales="free", ncol=2) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
         axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
         legend.position = "right",
         legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
         legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
         strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, color = "black"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `dumbbell::dumbbell` does some data pre-processing before constructing the dumbbell chart via `ggplot2`. Among other things unnecessary columns get dropped during this step, i.e. only the columns specified in the arguments of `dumbbell` are kept while all other columns which in your case includes your `Session` column get dropped. As a consequence you are not able to facet by `Session`.

One workaround would be to add a new key column to your data which is simply the interaction of `Trial_type` and `Session`. This key column you could then passed to the `key` argument off `dumbbell` and could be used as faceting variable:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dumbbell)

data10A$key <- paste(data10A$Trial_type, data10A$Session, sep = "\n")
dumbbell::dumbbell(data10A, id = "conditon2", key = "key",
                   leg = "Test", 
                   column1 = "NormalizedJerk_102", 
                   column2 = "NormalizedJerk_104", 
                   delt = 1, lab1 = "Pre-test", lab2 = "Post-test", 
                   p_col1 = "black", p_col2 = "grey40", 
                   textsize = 4, segsize = 1.5, 
                   pointsize = 2.5, 
                   title = "Change in Normalized jerk from Pre- to Post-test")  + 
  facet_wrap( ~ key, scales="free", ncol=2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, color = "black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Can you please help me edit the code with facet_nested. Thank you

Comment: Hi Reuben. TBMK that's not possible via `dumbbell` or with the workaround I showed in my answer as `facet_nested` requires two separate columns. If you require a specific faceting layout I would suggest to build the dumbbell chart from scratch using `geom_segment` and `geom_point`.

Comment: well taken, how about removing the y-axis label on the right plots to create space